# Replace \R is stripping the last character

Tags: regex, replace

I don't normally work with these expressions so I'm over my head here but close to making something work.

I'm using notepad++. I have text for which I'm trying to replace carriage returns with a comma, except where there are 2 returns.

After some searches, I found something that mostly works, but it's stripping the last character off of each line.

I'm replacing `[^\n\r]\R` with ,

data before replace:

```
00:67:z8:e4:f8:6d
192.168.255.42
Bethel
wifi
wifi
Unknown
802.11ac
Associated
No
8
1
No
No
No
No
Intel-Device
Disable

00:67:z8:8e:3e:35
192.168.255.61
IT
wifi
wifi
Unknown
802.11ac
Associated
No
8
1
No
No
No
No
Unclassified
Disable
```

Data after replace

```
00:67:z8:e4:f8:6,192.168.255.4,Bethe,wif,wif,Unknow,802.11a,Associate,N,,,N,N,N,N,Intel-Devic,Disabl,
00:67:z8:8e:3e:3,192.168.255.6,I,wif,wif,Unknow,802.11a,Associate,N,,,N,N,N,N,Unclassifie,Disabl,
```

It's perfect except for stripping off the last character. Can anyone tell me what dumb thing I'm missing?

Thanks!
John

Comment: The is because you are matching the last character and not keeping it in the replacement. You can use a capture group instead and use `$1` in the replacement. `([^\n\r])\R` See https://regex101.com/r/TeeUoX/1 Or use `[^\n\r]\K\R` and replace with only a comma https://regex101.com/r/GYHJRo/1

Comment: Don't capture the character you want to check. You can use look behind: `(?<![\n\r])\R`

Answer (score 0):

If you match the character and you want to keep it, the value of the matched character should be in the replacement or else it will not be there.

In Notepad++ you can use `\K` to forget what is matched so far.

```
[^\n\r]\K\R
```

In the replacement use only a comma.

[image]